# Arduino temperature conversion issues

Tags: arduino

my code won't convert Celsius to fahrenheit. The snippet of code is below. I can't find my mistake. my code outputs 90 when it should output 136.4.

```cpp
  float c= 58;
  float temp= (((9 / 5) * c + 32));
  Serial.println(temp);
```

Answer (score 2):

You are falling foul of integer division, for which `9 / 5` is equal to `1`, due to truncation. Change this line:

```c
 float temp= (((9 / 5) * c + 32));
```

to:

```c
 float temp= (((9.0 / 5.0) * c + 32.0));
```

Comment: using floating point operations on an arduino is not the best idea in the world...

Answer (score 2):

Using floating point operations on an arduino is costly. Contrary to most PC/supposedly smart phones etc., the arduino processor has no native floating point support. You might want to use integer arithmetics instead.

As a general rule, to avoid unwanted rounding, you should do all multiplications first, and only then divide. Unless the accumulated products overflow, of course.

here it would be :

```
int temp = (c*9)/5 + 32;
```

If you really need precision, you can for instance store the temperature in 1/100th of °.